# Values are not saved in mongodb

Tags: angular, mongodb, express

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.djamware.com/post/5b00bb9180aca726dee1fd6d/mean-stack-angular-6-crud-web-application) to set up a simple Angular 6/ExpressJS/mongoDb application. I had to make some changes on the ExpressJS side because I wanted to run Angular in a development env.

My issue is that when I save a book from my application "something" does happen. A new record is inserted into the mongoDb. This is the console log:

```
{
    author: "4"
    description: "4",     
    isbn: "4", 
    published_year: "4",
    publisher: "4",    
    title: "4", 
}
```

From the formSubmit function:

```
onFormSubmit(form:NgForm) {
  console.log(form);
  this.api.postBook(form)
    .subscribe(res => {
        let id = res['_id'];
        this.router.navigate(['/book-details', id]);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
}
```

This is also passed through to the `postBook` function in the api service.

So it looks like the data is being correctly inserted into the form and passed to ExpressJS.

When I run `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" localhost:3000/api` I do get results back:

```
[
    {"_id":"5b0e4f1dc547e5164c08acab","updated_date":"2018-05-30T07:13:33.050Z","__v":0},
    {"_id":"5b0e4fe74d3d0b15f44ed717","updated_date":"2018-05-30T07:16:55.392Z","__v":0},
    {"_id":"5b0e52c0b0710433b0986864","updated_date":"2018-05-30T07:29:04.551Z","__v":0},
    {"_id":"5b0e5356b0710433b0986865","updated_date":"2018-05-30T07:31:34.290Z","__v":0}
]
```

But as you can see no data from the front end is being stored in the database.

This is my Book.js model:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const apiRouter = require('./routes/book');
const logger = require('morgan');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/movieseat', { promiseLibrary: require('bluebird') })
  .then(() =>  console.log('connection successful'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

app.use(logger('dev'));  
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', apiRouter);
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))

module.exports = app;
```

So it looks like ExpressJS has a problem collecting/storing the data from the front-end. Any ideas on why that is or how to bugfix it?

Comment: can we see the `'./routes/book'`?
or at least the `/book-details` route handler?

Comment: please add the apiRouter code

Comment: Ah, looks like I was missing `app.use(express.json());`.

Comment: code is still missing, no way to help you if you don't provide it.

Comment: @JulienLeray oh sorry. The problem was I was missing the express.json function for ExpressJS. App is working fine now!